# How to prevent to update changed data

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I use SQL Azure and have application, which sync data with external resource. Data is huge, approx 10K records, so, I get it from DB one time, update something if necessary during some minutes and save changes. It works, but problem with simultaneously access to data. IF during these some minutes other service add changes, these changes will be rewritten.

But in the most cases it concerns fields, which my application does not touch!

So, for example, my Table `Device`:

```
public partial class Device : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IMEI { get; set; }

    public string SN { get; set; }

    public string ICCID { get; set; }

    public string MacAddress { get; set; }

    public DeviceStatus Status { get; set; }
```

first service (application with long-term process) can modify `SN`, `ICCID`, `MacAddress`, but not `Status`, second service, vice versa, can modify only `Status`.

Code to update in the first service:

```
        _allLocalDevicesWithIMEI = _context.GetAllDevicesWithImei().ToList();
```

(it gets entities, not DTO, because really there are many fields can be changed)

and then:

```
        _context.Devices.Update(localDevice);
```

for every device, which should be changed

and, eventually:

```
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How to mark, that field `Status` should be excluded from tracing?

Comment: Try using RowVersion and handle concurrency like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency

Answer (score 0):

One simple method to avoid update the status field when calling the first service is create a update entity not include the status field, and create another update entity for the second service which includes the status field.

Another way to resolve this problem is override the SaveChangesAsync method and control the update logic by yourself, but it's complex I think and the behavior is implicit, it will not easy for others to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid rewrite, you can specify RowVersion on entities. This is so called optimistic concurrency, it will throw error if rewrite happens and you can retry operation if someone already changed something. Or you can just level up your Transaction level, to something like RepeatableRead/Serialized to lock these rows for entire operation (which of course will pose huge performance impact and timeouts). Second option is simple, and good enough for background jobs and distributed transactions, first one is more flexible and usually faster. but hard to implement across multiple endpoints/entities.